# SPF: Sender Policy Framework (Too many included lookups)

Tags: email, spf

**Issue:** I don't understand SPF well enough to know where to post this question

**Goal:** Figure out how to include more than 10 valid senders to my SPF record

I currently have a warning on my SPF record that it violates RFC 7208 because it requires too many lookups. Unfortunately the number I've added is the number I need (I actually only have 6 senders on there) but that turns into 12.

I can't control what other domains do, if they are redirecting the domain they provide me for SPF also they can always change their domain again and turn my current 12 lookups to 15 for all I know.

We also aren't allowed have multiple SPF records on a given domain, so whats the answer? What if....I actually needed 12 senders? Is SPF broken for bigger organizations that require lots of senders, or am I missing the solution?

Comment: This answer from serverfault maybe you gona find a clue https://serverfault.com/a/265281